# How can I read the error message from stderr?

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, stdout, stderr

We are studying Pipes and I have to create a C code that reads the error message from compiling another c program. I am using dup2 to copy `stederr` to writing side of the pipe, after that I use `read` method to read from the other side of the pipe but in some cases I am not able to read the whole error message.
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *const cmd0 = argv[1];
    int fds_pair[2];
    pipe(fds_pair);
    
    pid_t pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {

        close(fds_pair[0]);

        /// stderr <- pipe's write
        dup2(fds_pair[1], 2);
        execlp("g++", "g++", cmd0, "-o", "my_program", NULL);
        return 0;

    } else {
        close(fds_pair[1]);
    
        char expression[256];
        memset(expression, '\0', sizeof(expression));
        size_t readret;            
        readret = read(fds_pair[0], &expression, sizeof(expression));
        printf("%s", expression);

        while (readret > 0) {
            readret = read(fds_pair[0], expression, sizeof(expression));
            printf("%s", expression);
        }
    }
    close(fds_pair[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

the problem that I am facing is that when I try to get the error of program :

```
1   #include <stdio.h>
2
3   int main () {
4     ;float v_05778c89;
5     float v_ char v_ int v_ double v_ double v_
6   }
```

Here is the error message that I read from the code above:

```
main2.c: In function ‘int main()’:
main2.c:5:5: error: expected initializer before ‘float’
5 |     float v_
  |     ^~~~~
```

I don't get the error:  *expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘*attribute*’ before ‘}’ token
6 | }*

I am confused about what I am doing wrong or what I have to fix

Comment: The semicolon before the first `float` is weird.  If you have a compiler that doesn't accept C99 or later, it might be the cause of your trouble.  The absence of a semicolon after `v_` is definitely a problem — five times over.  The repetition of `v_` is another problem.  …Or is that an erroneous source file that you're compiling and you are trying but failing to get the error messages from the compilation?  It isn't absolutely clear.  If the latter, there's nowhere near enough code to tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: the test cases are generated automatically so I can't do anything about them

Comment: Please clarify your question.  And show the code that is supposed to launch the compilation and capture the error output.  We really don't need very much of the erroneous C code that you're compiling — it would be sufficient that you have `gcc -c erroneous.c` to work with as a command line.  That'll fail if there isn't a file `erroneous.c` to compile, and should also fail if `erroneous.c` contains erroneous code.  We need to see your code that is launching the compiler and organizing the I/O redirections as well as reading the supposedly redirected error output.

Comment: I have edited the code I hope it is good now

Comment: You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the either the parent or the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the original file descriptors from `pipe()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions. The parent should close the write end of the pipe. The child should close both. Your indentation leaves much to be desired.

Comment: Note that `read()` does not null terminate strings, and it doesn't pay attention to line boundaries.  You should probably use `printf("%.*s", (int)readret, expression);` to print the data from `read()` sanely.  The cast is necessary for the code to be reliable/portable; the `*` expects an `int` and not a `size_t`.

Comment: Thank you so much and excuse me please I am not used to ask questions here. You are right I didn't close the writing side of the pipe in the parent but I didn't get what is wrong with the child?

Comment: You have `dup2(fds_pair[1], 2);` which is fine (though some would argue that you should use `STDERR_FILENO` instead of `2`).  But you now have no further use for `fds_pair[1]` in the child, so you should close it.  It probably won't matter in this case, but it is sloppy to leave the (unused) file descriptor open.

Comment: General comment: you should probably read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242169/discussion-between---and-jonathan-leffler).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you expect (`expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘attribute’ before ‘}’ token 6 | }`) is typical of MS Visual C++, not GNU `g++`.  That may be the main problem — unrealistic expectations.

I amended your code to include the first paragraph of code from my version, shown below, so that `argc` is used and it passes my default compilation options.
When I run your amended code (source file `re23.c` compiled to `re23`), I get the output:

```
$ re23 main2.c
main2.c: In function ‘int main()’:
main2.c:5:12: error: expected initializer before ‘char’
    5 |   float v_ char v_ int v_ double v_ double v_
      |            ^~~~
main2.c: In function ‘int main()’:
main2.c:5:12: error: expected initializer before ‘char’
    5 |   float v_ char v_ int v_ double v_ double v_
      |            ^~~~
$
```

The message appears twice because you don't deal with the I/O from the child process (the C++ compiler) correctly.  Basically, you need to read the data and check that it worked at all before you print anything.

Compilation (GCC 11.2.0 running on macOS Big Sur 11.6.4):

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-common re23.c -o re23
$
```

I mentioned various problems in the comments, too.  I believe they're all fixed in the code below, which works OK according to my standards.  It's similar to yours, and is closely based on yours, but has a few key differences.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s sourcefile.cpp\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    const char *const cmd0 = argv[1];
    int fds_pair[2];
    if (pipe(fds_pair) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to create pipe: %d %s\n",
                argv[0], errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to fork: %d %s\n",
                argv[0], errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(fds_pair[1], STDERR_FILENO);
        close(fds_pair[0]);
        close(fds_pair[1]);
        execlp("g++", "g++", cmd0, "-o", "my_program", NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to exec '%s': %d %s\n",
                argv[0], "g++", errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        close(fds_pair[1]);
        char expression[256];
        ssize_t readret;
        while ((readret = read(fds_pair[0], &expression, sizeof(expression))) > 0)
        {
            printf("%.*s", (int)readret, expression);
        }
        close(fds_pair[0]);
        int corpse;
        int status;
        while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
            printf("%s: child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", argv[0], corpse, status);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here are some sample runs — I used source code `re37.c` for the source above, creating the program `re37`:

```
$ ./re37
Usage: ./re37 sourcefile.cpp
$ ./re37 nonexistent.cpp
cc1plus: fatal error: nonexistent.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
./re37: child 4644 exited with status 0x0100
$ cat main2.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  ;float v_05778c89;
  float v_ char v_ int v_ double v_ double v_
}
$ ./re37 main2.c
main2.c: In function ‘int main()’:
main2.c:5:12: error: expected initializer before ‘char’
    5 |   float v_ char v_ int v_ double v_ double v_
      |            ^~~~
./re37: child 4670 exited with status 0x0100
$
```